# Atmel SAM D21 Frequency Capture

Tags: timer, frequency, atmel

I am currently struggling with the frequency capture function of the Atmel's SAM D21 frequency capture mode of TC/TCC Timer Counter Capture Module and the Event System.

After profound examination of the datasheet I am still not aware of how I can set the analog input. I am trying to measure the frequency of a PWM signal of a photo transistor. Can anyone tell me where or how I can select the analog input of the frequency capture module?

Regards.